# Browser window shows correct value in inspector but invalid in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dom

I am dynamically generating the input box using jquery and then embedding it into the document. The problem I am having is, although the correct value is being shown in the inspector, the browser shows an invalid value.

To be further clear, here is the image:
[image]

You can see that, in the inspector
`<input name="txtTblAmount" class="num" style="width:70px;" type="text" value="1000" tabindex="29">`

the value is 1000 while that being shown in the browser window is 1500. Can anyone please have a look and tell me, what's the problem here?

P.S: Have tried it in firefox as well. But still the problem is same i.e. different value in the inspector.

Here is the JS code:

```
function addrow(itemName, itemid, godown, godownid, quantity, rate, amount, gstAmount) {

        gstAmount = typeof gstAmount !== 'undefined' ? gstAmount : '0';

        if (typeof dTable1 != 'undefined') {
            // dTable1.fnClearTable();
            //$('#ItemRows').find('a[name="btnDelItem"]').off();
            dTable1.fnDestroy();
            // $('#ItemRows').empty();
        }
        //alert($('#ItemRows tr').length);
        var strRow = '<tr id="row' + ($('#ItemRows tr').length + 1) + '">' +
             '<td class="">' +
            (($('#ItemRows tr').length + 1)) +
              '</td>' +
              '<td class="tdItemName" style="widtd: 250px">' +
               itemName +
             '<input name="hfItemId" style="width:200px;" type="hidden" value="' + itemid + '"/>' +
              '</td>' +
              '<td class="" style="widtd: 200px">' +
                godown +
                '<input name="hfGodownid" style="width:200px;" type="hidden" value="' + godownid + '"/>' +
                 '</td>' +
                 '<td class="" style="widtd: 200px">' +
                 '<input name="txtTblQuantity" style="width:200px;" class="num"  type="text" value="' + quantity + '"/>' +
                  '</td>' +
                   '<td class="" style="widtd: auto">' +
                  '<input name="txtTblRate" style="width:70px;" class="num"   type="text" value="' + rate + '"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                 '<td class="" style="widtd: auto">' +
                  '<input name="txtTblAmount" class="num"  style="width:70px;" type="text" value="' + amount + '"/>' +
                 '</td>' +
                 '<td>' +
                 '<input name="txtTblGstAmount" class="num"  style="width:70px;" type="text" value="' + gstAmount + '"/>' +
                 '</td>' +
                '<td class="ms"><div class="btn-group1"> <a class="btn btn-small" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title=" edit " name="btnDelItem" data-id="' + ($('#ItemRows tr').length + 1) + '"  ><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>  </div></td>' +

                '</tr>';
        console.log(strRow);
        console.log(amount);

        $('#ItemRows').append(strRow);
        //SaveNewParty($("#drpAccId option:selected").text());
        bindGrid();
        //dTable1.fnDraw();
        PopulateTotal();
        // $('#ItemRows').find('a[name="btnDelItem"]').off();
        var insertedRow = $('#ItemRows tr')[$('#ItemRows tr').length - 1];
        $(insertedRow).find('a[name="btnDelItem"]').on('click', function () {
            var row = $(this).parents('tr');
            dTable1.fnDeleteRow(dTable1.fnGetPosition(row[0]));
            $('#ItemRows tr').each(function (index) {
                $(this).find('td:nth(0)').text((index + 1));

            });

            PopulateTotal();


        })
        $('#datatable_Items').css('width', '100%');
        Populate_Events();
    }
```

Comment: You could be setting that value thru JS

Comment: Quite often the value in the inspector is not the value of the element. You will find that if you run (and set a breakpoint in chrome) that the value is 1500. Is it a problem that the two dont match?

Comment: Yes, because what I actually want is 1000, and that I have set using JS as well! But it is somehow showing 1500. I have tried reloading as well, but nothing worked.

Comment: the problem is in your code... and I can't see your code... I tried looking at the back of the image but there's no code in there... :|

Comment: lol @Reigel, I have added the code! Please have a look, if you find any problem

Comment: @Reigel Haven't you checked the code yet?

Comment: Can you post a running fiddle?

Comment: Impossible in this case, as the code is much complicated and gets it's data from various sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at your code and found that there was no problem in the code you have shown us here. I agree with Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan but the way he has explained it, it's not always the case. I recently had the same issue and after hours of scratching my head I found out that the value was being changed by some other jquery code.

Also note that, it is not always the case that the value set by the jquery is shown in the inspector for example, if you try `$("#inputel").val(4)`, you will note that the value will not be updated in the inspector but in the backend this value has been updated. Inspector only shows the value that was sent from the server, not the one you set by jquery or something else.

Hope you got my point!

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer that I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Kamran, that's of no importance. You are setting this value **NOT DYNAMICALLY**. Yes, you can see here! You are either setting this value while loading the page, or you are using some other code, that you are not showing us! I am not sure of that. Ok here.

[image]

In my example you can see, I am writing a text in the input but there is no value update in the element's inspection.

Also, its maybe not the answer but you can see that you're using `widtd` which is not a correct CSS property. The correct one is `width`. You know that.

I am sure you won't get any problem while sending the form to the server, as the value will get updated by the value that you just wrote.

I have seen your code, you are writing the field as:

```
<input name="txtTblAmount" class="num"  
style="width:70px;" type="text" value="' + amount + '"/>'
```

According to me, the issue is at `amount`. You are havin this field in the function too.

```
function addrow(itemName, itemid, godown, 
godownid, quantity, rate, amount, gstAmount) {
```

Now what you can do to prevent that is to change the value of `amount` there. If you donot want to change it, then its OK. And also, once again you should not fear this value difference, as once you click `submit` the value that you have entered will be sent to the server instead of `value` of the field itself. The value is just because you have it written there. Nothing else, so don't worry! Its ok. You cannot change the value now, if you want to. Then here is the hell code, you will have to hard code it. Like this!

```
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" id="text" value="" onkeyup="updateVal()" />
</div>

function updateVal() {
  // start function..
  var val = $('#text').val(); // the value of field..
  // after getting the value, update the div..
  $('#input').html("<input type='text' id='text' value='" + 
  val + "' onkeyup='updateVal()' />");
}
```

But note, after using this code, you will get the current value in the field! But you will loose the focus on the input field. As the div will get updated but the values will be the newest ones!

**Now to keep in focus?**

You can use this:

```
$('#text').focus();
```

But while using this, you will get only one **ONLY ONE** word in the field.

**Why?**

Because once if will focus on the field, it will (select all) select the words or value inside the field and when you press  another word, it will replace the previous one with the latest one! This way you will not get any correct field I mean the field of your choice! But you issue will be fixed.

So kamran believe me, let it be the way it is! You donot want to hard-code it. If you still wanna give it a try, use the code I shared!

Example for the code I am sharing is as under:

[image: zero value]

Now when you right the value or some words, you will get the value auto updated when you see this Developer Tools. Like this:

[image]

That was all. I gave you two options for your work. And still I will love to go with the option of **Not using a code, to just update the value on the field**. Rest is upto you Kamran.

**Edit:**

You mentioed that you want to use the value `1000` not the value that the user would add to the input. Then use this:

```
$("name='txtTblAmount'").val() == "1000");
```

This will automatically override the value that user will add and replace it with the value that you want to get!

Comment: I have tried changing the value in the inspector for another input and it did change it in the browser document. But for this specific input it doesn't change even if I change it in the inspector.

Comment: Have you tried the code I sent? You will update the value there using the JS dynamically! But still can I know why you want this to be updated? It will never mess up any of the inputs that will be sent to server!

Comment: What you have told is correct but that's not what I am asking about. Actually in my case the value I want to be sent to the server is 1000 i.e. the one written in the inspector i.e. the one that I have set by myself using JS, not the one writte inside the browser document. The browser is somehow duplicating the value of  the next input field

Comment: Its your fault, you have not told us that you want something like that! You have just told us that you are writing 1500 but the value in inspector is 1000. How can we come to the conclusion :/ ?? Ok, then you can use this:

Comment: you can see my edit! I have made an edit, so that you could override the value that user would provide with the one you are trying to be added there!

Comment: and you down voted me only because I was helping you and you were not clarifying the issue? :/ thats not fair buddy..

Comment: Thanks for "trying to help" but your answer doesn't make any sense with what I am trying to ask!!

Comment: What you have asked doesn't make any sense. I have explained what you're asking. You can ask for anything else, without arguing!